# Setting a format to a date retrieved by entity in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Considering my model contains only :

```
public class TheModel
{
    public SQL_Table TableInModel { get; set; }
}
```

`SQL_Table` is a table retrieved with Entity Framework (I use SQL Server and EF).

I can retrieve the table object in the controller using :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ControllerName(TheModel mod)
{
    mod.TableInModel = db.SQL_Table.First();
    return View(mod);
}
```

Now binding that date correctly in a view... I tried :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.TableInModel.Date, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" )
```

Which format the date correctly, but the value in the textbox is lost on postback and cannot be retrieved in the controller.

So I tried this instead :

```
@Html.EditorFor(t => t.TableInModel.Date)
```

This correctly send the date value to my controller on postback, but no format is applied on the textBox that is generated.

What is the way to format a date in this context while being sure the value isn't lost on postback ?

(when I try this in my controller `mod.TableInModel.Date` Date is null)

This is my web output :

[image: My web output]

Comment: In what way is the value "lost"?  What is the resulting HTML for these two attempts and how does it differ between them?

Comment: in the controller, mod.TableInModel.Date is NULL

Comment: Which would imply that what's being posted is somehow different, so you should definitely check the HTML generated by these attempts to see how they differ.  Perhaps the resulting `name` value is different?

Comment: I added the output in my question, name is the same

Comment: What do you mean its `null`? Is your property `DateTime?` (nullable)? And what is the culture on your server - is it one that accepts dates in `dd-M-yyyy` format?

Comment: @StephenMuecke in the database, it is a DateTime, when entity brings it in my app, it is a DateTime? so yes, a nullable dateTime var, it's irrelevant it because it work with an Editor for... it just displays wrong

Comment: You need to set the `[DataType]` attribute on the property when using `EditorFor()`. But if your getting `null` for a date which is 21st June (formatted as `21-6-2016`), then it means the culture on your server does not accept dates in the `dd-MM-yyyy` format. Check if its correctly binding for a date which is say 2nd January

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make another property for everything that dosen't post back correctly and assign it into your controller, it's not worth trying to format AND retreive a property created by entity :

```
public class TheModel
{
    public SQL_Table TableInModel { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date {get;set;} // <- apply your format HERE
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ControllerName(TheModel mod)
{
    mod.TableInModel = db.SQL_Table.First();
    mod.Date = mod.TableInModel.Date; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try all these steps.  It displays the date time formatted and binds and returns the right value, but with a time, since if you use the sql date time, edmx, stores this value as a datetime.  You can strip off the time, shown below.  I can't even find .net date type that is not datetime.

create the sql server table exactly:

```
USE [Breaz]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SQL_Table]    Script Date: 11/30/2016 1:34:35 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SQL_Table](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TheDate] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SQL_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Add one row of data

Add the edmx

Here is the controller:

```
public class TheModel
{
    public SQL_Table TableInModel { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult IndexC()
    {
        BreazEntities1 db = new BreazEntities1();
        var mod = new TheModel();
        mod.TableInModel = db.SQL_Table.Find(1);
        //the Key to this solution is that the type in sql
        //is Date instead of DateTime or the "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"
        //If you insist on datetime then, even if you
        //format the time out of the date, if you bind it
        //back to a datetime field, the time will still be there
        //albeit 00:00:00
        //finds my first, by identity, row in sql_table wich has 
        //TheDate Column that are passing to view and back
        //out to controller          
        return View(mod);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexC(TheModel sql_table)
    {
        //finds my first, by identity, row in sql_table wich has 
        //don't let the code advance past here
        //we can interrogate the sql_table variable and see 
        //that the formatted date is coming back
        var removeTime = sql_table.TableInModel.TheDate.ToShortDateString();

        return View();
    }
```

Here is the view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@model WebApplication1.Controllers.TheModel

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>IndexC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TableInModel.TheDate, "{0:d MMM yyyy}")
            <input type="submit" value="Passing formatted date." />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It pretty much answers my question with the first paragraphe you wrote, there is no "Date only" type in .net framework. So unless making some kind of work around or changing the SQL part, it is not managed in MVC that an entity database first would but place in a html page as it is. i'm going to edit your answer and add another work around and i will then accept it.